# Нужна ли запятая в сочетании «неужели, чтобы...»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая после слова "неужели" в этом предложении?
**Неужели, чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него позволение.**

Answer (score 2):

Да, здесь запятая нужна. 
"Неужели" хоть и произносится связано (интонационно) с "чтобы", но грамматически это часть другого предложения - частица со значением "правда ли", "верно ли".

Кстати, придаточное "чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие" можно без потери смысла и грамматики перенести в другую часть предложения, в конец, например, при этом "неужели" никак нельзя отцепить от начала основного предложения. Это тоже косвенный признак необходимости запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Мнения по данному вопросу разделились с перевесом в сторону постановки **запятой**: 3 ответа — "за", 1 — "против", 1 (участник София) — больше "против", хотя в дополнении к ответу объясняется возможность "за".

Руководствуясь неоднократно рекомендованными принципами пунктуации (смысл, грамматика, интонация), считаю, что **запятая нужна**. При решении сразу отбрасываю интонацию, поскольку принципиального значения в данном случае она не имеет, тем более что эта область довольно субъективная и во многих случаях споры заходят в тупик.

Семантика предложения понятна: ***неужели*** относится к главному безличному ***нужно спрашивать***, а не к ***чтобы доставить удовольствие***.

Грамматика ещё прозрачнее. В одном из ответов написано: "Перестановка предложений невозможна, так как "человек" в придаточном предложении заменяется местоимением "у него" в главном". Не согласен. Разве при разборе предложения и перестановке частей мы должны ориентироваться только на исходную последовательность слов? Это формальность. Главное здесь снова смысл. В итоге придаточное уходит в конец (как предлагает участник behemothus):

***Неужели нужно*** (запятая, естественно, отсутствует) ***предварительно спрашивать у человека позволение, чтобы доставить ему удовольствие?***

Нацкорпус русского языка по запросу "**неужели чтобы**" выдаёт всего 22 документа. Из них только один (сомнительный, по словам behemothus, с чем я согласен) не имеет запятой перед "*чтобы*", хотя "*неужели*" тоже относится к главному предложению. Ещё два случая не имеют запятой по понятной причине — "*неужели*" вводит придаточные, вынесенные в отдельные предложения, и относится именно к ним:

*Было неясно, для чего покинула она прежнего мужа. **Неужели чтобы** народить такого никчемного мужичонку?* [Владимир Личутин. Любостай (1987)]

***Неужели чтобы** следить, не изменяет ли этот рыжий биржевик своей половине?* [И. Г. Эренбург. Необычайные похождения Хулио Хуренито (1921)]

В остальных примерах **запятая ставится**, например:

***Неужели, чтобы** стать известным, надо превратиться в бронзу?* [И. И. Старцев. Мои встречи с Есениным (1926.03.15)]

***Неужели, чтобы** он это вспомнил, предварительно нужна война?* [Михаил Анчаров. Золотой дождь (1965)]

*Лелик был на два года старше меня, **неужели, чтобы** справиться со мной, ему нужен тесак?* [Юрий Нагибин. Тьма в конце туннеля (1994)]

И есть даже три случая, когда запятая между нашими частицей и союзом стоит несмотря на то, что частица относится к придаточному (это примеры под номерами 3, 10 и 14, при желании [можно посмотреть](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1979&text=lexform&req=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&endyear=1999&nodia=1&p=0)). Это, думается, тоже сомнительно.

Comment: Александр, вот вы пишете: "Семантика предложения понятна: "неужели" относится к главному безличному "нужно спрашивать", а не к "чтобы доставить удовольствие".  Но "неужели" - это частица, а частицы обычно относятся или  слову, или ко всему предложению. Но всё предложение здесь - это СПП. Может ли частица относится только к главной его части, да еще на расстоянии от нее?

Comment: @Sharon А вот здесь как раз я бы включил гипотетический вариант интонации. После "неужели" человек как бы запнулся, задумался... и ввернул придаточное перед главным.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед придаточным предложением нужна. Правило о неотделении частицы от простого подчинительного союза не универсально: оно касается не всех частиц и не всех позиций в предложении.

Во-первых, придаточная часть должна следовать за главной (это условие прописано и у Розенталя, и в ПАС Лопатина).

Во-вторых, у Розенталя это правило касается только частицы *не*: *Спишь не когда хочешь, а когда можешь.*

Лопатин дублирует это правило, но добавляет к другому правилу Розенталя ("если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз *и, или, либо* и т. д. (обычно повторяющийся): *Учтите и что он сказал, и как он это сказал*") слово "частица":
 "если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз и (**или частица**): Не вернул он мне книгу и когда прочитал ее".

При этом ни одного примера с частицей Лопатин не приводит и уже в следующих пунктах противоречит себе, говоря: "Если перед простым подчинительным союзом стоят усилительно-ограничительные слова (**частицы**, союзы или их сочетания, вводные слова) *особенно, даже, в частности, в том числе, в особенности, а именно, а также, а (но) только, как раз, лишь, исключительно, только* и др., то запятая ставится перед ними, а не перед союзом: *Он приехал в Москву, исключительно чтобы попасть в Большой театр*".

Кроме небольшого недоразумения у Лопатина не вижу ничего, что можно было бы добавить к Розенталю:

1. Не ставится запятая между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения, если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит отрицательная частица *не*.
2. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные частицы *как раз, только, лишь, исключительно* и т. п., то запятая ставится перед ними вопреки интонации (при чтении пауза перед ними не делается).
3. Не ставится запятая после выделительных частиц *вот, ведь,* стоящих перед подчинительным союзом в придаточной части, предшествующей главной: *Вот как работу выполним, тогда приезжайте*.

Comment: Вот интересная ситуация: Розенталь с Лопатиным не решили задачу, где фигурирует именно частица НЕУЖЕЛИ, а не какая другая, и вся пунктуация встала. Решение таково: роемся в правилах и пытаемся их экстраполировать за их пределы. А если решить задачу от нуля, своими силами, просто используя три основных пунктуационных принципа. Просто следует назвать смысл, интонацию и грамматику для двух вариантов и сравнить их.

Comment: Можно, конечно, и с нуля начать - и даже интересно. Только, если мы посоветуем Анне не ставить запятую, хорошую оценку она не получит. А если порассуждать, то "неужели" здесь относится к главному предложению и придаточное явно "выпадает". На паузы же при постановке запятых лучше не ориентироваться: если для интонационного тире они что-то значат, то в случае запятых очень ненадежный критерий.

Answer (score 1):

"Неужели, чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него позволение?" Разумеется, запятая нужна. "Неужели (пояснительное предложение выброшено) нужно предварительно спрашивать у него позволение?". Этот случай простой. В более сложных надо смотреть со всех сторон - и всё-таки сделать ошибку (по мнению несогласных). Живой язык трудно разложить по косточкам. Если уж Лопатин с Розенталем спорят, то нам сам Бог велел

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что можно запятую не ставить: "Неужели чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него позволение?"

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Неужели - это частица, а частицы обычно не отделяются запятой от подчинительных союзов.

Интонационной паузы нет.

Частицу "неужели" можно отнести ко всему СПП.

Перестановка предложений невозможна, так как "человек" в придаточном предложении заменяется местоимением "у него" в главном.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1. Если принять решение о постановке запятой, это решение надо доказать.
2. Думаю,  что все представленные здесь рассуждения такой выбор НИСКОЛЬКО НЕ ДОКАЗЫВАЮТ, так как НЕУЖЕЛИ  – это вопросительная частица и она относится ко всему предложению, в то время как  усилительные и выделительные частицы  (ТОЛЬКО, СОВЕРШЕННО и др.)  относятся к конкретному слову.
3. ДОКАЗАТЬ можно следующим образом. Попробуем изменить предложение:  «Неужели  для того,  чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него разрешение».

Здесь используется СОСТАВНОЙ СОЮЗ, который расчленяется под действием  ЛЕКСИЧЕСКОГО АКТУАЛИЗАТОРА,  в роли которого выступает частица НЕУЖЕЛИ. 
Если местоименную часть союза опустить, то  «неужели» будет выполнять роль пропущенной части союза, и мы будем иметь расчлененный союз  НЕУЖЕЛИ, ЧТОБЫ вместо НЕУЖЕЛИ ДЛЯ ТОГО, ЧТОБЫ.
Информация о лексических актуализаторах  взята из Грамматики-80.

http://rusgram.narod.ru/3058-3077.html

Comment: Местоимение "у него" можно выкинуть без потери смысла.

Comment: Конечно, можно догадаться, у кого не надо спрашивать позволение, но без местоимения фраза смотрится как неполная, незаконченная.

Comment: >Частицу "неужели" можно отнести ко всему СПП.  
  
Боюсь, что нет. А как?
И потом, что это дает в данном случае?

http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E5%F3%E6%E5%EB%E8+%F7%F2%EE%E1%FB

из первых десяти - только один пример без запятой из весьма спорного источника.

Comment: В идеале хотелось бы получить ответ на вопрос "Почему нужна запятая, не смотря на то что она стоит после слова "неужели". В учебнике русского языка четко написано: "после "неужели" запятая не ставится". А автор (Чехов) ставит. Почему?

Comment: >В учебнике русского языка четко написано: "после "неужели" запятая не ставится".  
  
Так поймите, эта запятые "не после неужели", а "перед чтобы". ;))) 
Ну неужели же одно правило отменяет другое, абсолютное - об обособлении придаточных?  
  
Другое дело, что при некоторых условиях частицу никак нельзя отрывать от придаточного. Но это, похоже, к нашему случаю это не относится.

Да, Anna, **награждать** баллами не стоит. Они Вам пригодятся. Лучще воспользоваться кнопочками с пальцами и галочками.

Comment: Вообще-то "неужели" - это вопросительная частица, и у нее есть синонимы. Мы же не будем ставить запятую в следующем предложении: "Разве чтобы что-то оценить , нужно это что-то потерять"?

Comment: >Мы же не будем... 
   
А разве кто-то предлагал?  
Зато:  
Разве, чтобы произвести его в себе, чтобы нечто подавить в истине или прибавить к ней, не требуется всякий раз некоторое усилие; и откуда было бы оно, если бы уже от начала человеческая природа была безразлично наклонна как ко лжи, так и к истине?  
(В.В. Розанов)  

Вообще замена "неужели" на разве не совсем удачна. "Разве" более многозначна. Она может иметь значение юлизкое, например, к "кроме":

К лягушкам он так и не преодолел брезгливости, ел их, разве чтобы не умереть с голоду. 
(В. Быков)

Примеры - из наукорпуса.

Comment: Я предлагаю:) В каком правиле сказано, что вопросительная частица не отделяется от подчинительного союза, да еще если придаточное предшествует главному?

Comment: Есть ли в правилах русского языка правило, что одно правило не отменяет другого или же это нечто само собой разумеющееся?

Comment: Общего правила обо всех частицах перед простым подчинительным союзом нет. Есть правила об отдельных частицах. При этом подразумевается, что другие частицы от союза отделяются.

Comment: **Anna**
    
Это нечто само собой разумеющееся. Если есть правило, по которому надо поставить какой-то пунктуационный знак (и нет оговоренных исключений или дополнений к этому правилу), то он ставится независимо от того, сколько еще есть других правил.   
  
Ну вот сравните. В русском языке предложение начинается с заглавной. Вы же не будете требовать писать имена собственныt в средине предложения со строчной на том основании, что это не начало предложения?!  
   
Так и тут. Если по одному правилу запятая не нужна, а по другому, с первым никак не связанному? нужна, то она ставится.

Comment: @София, В ответ на "ДОКАЗАТЬ можно следующим образом. Попробуем изменить предложение: «Неужели для того, чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него разрешение». "

Это докажет лишь то, что запятая ставится не после "неужели", а перед "чтобы". Никто же не сомневается, что в предложении «Неужели для этого нужно предварительно спрашивать у него разрешение?» запятые не нужны.

Comment: Неужели - это частица, и по правилам она не должна обособляться. Но здесь случай особый. "Неужели" действительно не обособляется, но она не обособляется от пропущенной местоименной части РАСЧЛЕНЕННОГО союза: "неужели (для того), чтобы". В результате  имеем расчлененный союз "неужели, чтобы".

Comment: Не пойму, о каком правиле речь. Нет такого правила, чтобы вопросительная частица не отделялась от подчинительного союза (и тем более от его местоименной части). Возможны 2 варианта: неужели, для того чтобы... и неужели для того, чтобы... (привязки к местоименной части нет).

Comment: А что касается утверждения, что вопросительная частица относится ко всему предложению, это легко опровергнуть, обратив внимание на смысл. При отсутствии запятой он искажается: Неужели чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него позволение? = Неужели спрашивать позволение нужно, чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие? = Зачем это нужно? Неужели чтобы доставить удовольствие? А здесь смысл "неужели надо спрашивать?".

Comment: http://modernlib.ru/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_13/

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, запятая здесь не нужна. Вот правильная пунктуация: "Неужели чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него позволение?" Объяснение очень простое. Неужели является не предложением и не вводным словом, а всего лишь частицей. Запятой не отделяется. Чтобы не путаться, просто добавляйте впереди мысленно "для того". Получится: "Неужели для того чтобы доставить человеку удовольствие, нужно предварительно спрашивать у него позволение?" Вот пример: Для того чтобы капуста оставалась хрустящей, не стоит слишком сильно перетирать её с солью (А. В. Кривцова. Разносолы из капусты. Готовим, как профессионалы). Добавляем вначале слово "неужели" и получаем то же самое. А вот и само правило: "В начале предложения подчинительный составной союз «для того чтобы» не делится на части, а запятая ставится на границе зависимого и главного предложения, то есть в конце придаточного цели". Добавьте сюда правило "неужели является частицей и не отделяется запятыми". Не благодарите за правильный ответ.

Comment: Иван Александрович,  а вы в Нацкорпус не заглядывали? Там из 22 примеров без запятой только три. http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=неужели+чтобы

Comment: *Неужели является не предложением и не вводным словом* - Неужели(,) уважаемый Иван Александрович, вы будете против и этой запятой? Или для вас тут "неужели" станет вводным?!

Comment: @Sharon *Там из 22 примеров без запятой только три* - причем два из этих трех не являются СПП и для запятой действительно нет мотива. А третий (автора некоего Александра Избицера).. - ну тут Бог судья. Я полагаю, ошибка.