# Пропуск союзного слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

В наземном транспорте Москвы слышал объявление:

> Ваш билет — это подтверждение, что поездка застрахована.

Я так понимаю, что пропуск "того" характерен для разговорной речи, но строго недопустим. А насколько, по-вашему, для разговорной это нормально?

Comment: *Я так понимаю, что пропуск "того" характерен для разговорной речи, но строго недопустим* - что-то я сильно сомневаюсь в недопустимости даже для "строгой" речи. Меня больше тире перед "это" забавляет. Вроде как бы и на месте оно , а смотрится плохо... Оно точно там было? Над вопросом подумаю.

Comment: *Оно точно там было?* — я же слышал, а не читал. Поставил, как самому пришло в голову.

Comment: А, пардон. Ментальность моя подвела. ))) Я давно уже не был ни в каком траспорте, а когда был, объявления не слушал, но всегда все читал.  )))

Comment: *...но всегда все читал* — ха-ха)) Просто я часто в таких случаях не ставил тире, но мне все тут на сайте пеняли — ай-яй-яй! Перед "это" обязательно надо ставить!

Comment: Артем, а вы не помните, как произносилась эта фраза? Перед ЭТО была пауза? Что-то мне тире тоже подозрительным кажется. На три части это предложение не делится, пауза должна быть в одном месте.

Comment: @Sharon: не было паузы. Так я тоже в таких случаях без паузы не ставил тире интуитивно, пока мне все хором не закричали, что оно перед "это" необходимо!

Comment: Спасибо, Артем. А как вы думаете, это предложение можно произнести  с паузой перед ЭТО?  Удобно  для вас такое произношение или что-то мешает? Ведь интонация в таких предложениях очень важна, в этой теме постановка тире иногда напрямую зависит от паузы.

Comment: Мне кажется, если и можно, то это будет неправильно. Потому что тут не определение "билета", а такой случай, когда тире можно заменить словом "служит" (служит подтверждением). И вам спасибо, что помогаете разобраться в этом вопросе! ;)

Comment: Да, интересно. Я чуть позже попробую ответить вам. Мне нравятся вопросы, в которых есть какое-то противоречие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ второй

Не понравился мне мой первый ответ, вернее, его отсутствие. В конце концов, Александр прав: вопрос совсем не о тире и называется он "Пропуск союзного слова". Правда, речь идет об указательном слове (это желательно бы исправить).

Вот об указательном слове (корреляте) и надо говорить. В ответе Александра приведены примеры без указательного слова, но что из этого следует? Оно всегда отсутствует или факультативно, в частности в заданном предложении? Полагаю, что тема там тоже не полностью раскрыта.

**Часть А. Ответ на вопрос о сомнительном тире (не совсем по теме)**

Определять грамматические паузы в устной речи довольно сложно, поэтому спорить об этом нет никакого смысла. Но есть более убедительное средство – это **тонические ударения.** Фонетическая фраза может содержать несколько произносительных пауз, но в ней всегда **только одно ударение.**

В этом предложении возможны такие варианты:

Ваш **билЕт** – это подтверждение, // что поездка **застрахОвана**. Ваш билет – это **подтверждЕние,** // что поездка **застрахОвана**.

Попробуем поставить три (силовых!) ударения, чтобы обозначить три фразы, и предложение просто «развалится» на три отдельные части, не связанные между собой: **Ваш билЕт** – //это **подтверждЕние**, // что поездка **застрахОвана.**

И вывод: здесь только две фразы с двумя ударениями. У нас **нет возможности обозначить ударением и полноценной паузой поставленное тире**.

**Часть Б. Ответ на вопрос (уже по теме)**

**1) Несколько слов о коррелятах (указательных словах)**

В качестве коррелята выступает местоимение ТО в различных падежах. При местоименной связи **коррелят обязателен +К**: *Он сказал **то, что** все давно уже знали.* Это местоименно-определительное СПП.

В изъяснительных СПП (связь союзная) коррелят **факультативен ±К**, однако там возможны такие варианты : **коррелят запрещен -К**, **коррелят обязателен +К**.

Например: *Он обещал **то, что** скоро приедет.* Попробуйте так сказать, и все укажут вам на грубую ошибку, так как здесь коррелят недопустим. Почему? Вероятно, пара ***то – что*** в И.п. имитирует местоименную связь, которой здесь нет. Сравнить: *Он говорил **о том, что** скоро приедет, займется делами*. Здесь указательное слово можно использовать.

Другой пример: *Он целый день занимался **тем, что** ремонтировал машину.* Здесь коррелят **обязателен,** без него никак. Это особый тип предложения, которые называются **«вмещающие изъяснительные»**.

Но в нашем случае (для опорного существительного ***подтверждение***) указательное слово **факультативно**. Заглянем в Нацкорпус и увидим: ***подтверждение, что*** – 67 примеров, ***подтверждение того, что*** – 136 примеров.

Что-то заставляет пользователей использовать указательное слово, хотя, казалось бы, без него можно обойтись. Вероятно, это зависит **от структуры конкретного предложения**, которую надо всегда учитывать.

Рассмотрим примеры с указательным словом:

Всего лишь еще одно подтверждение **того, что** ничего не изменилось… [Анна Берсенева (2003-2005)]

― В подтверждение **того, что** вы никаких претензий к нам не имеете. [Андрей Геласимов. (2009)]

Это подтверждение **того, что** ученики академика Коптюга не только помнят о нём, но и продолжают его дело. [Владимир Губарев2009]

В частности при наличии ***ЭТО*** коррелят используется всегда, выражение «**это подтверждение, что**» не имеет примеров в Нацкорпусе. Можно предположить, что местоименная связь ***это – что*** (И.п.) делает содержание предложения неясным.

И такой вывод: **в заданном предложении коррелят обязателен:**

*Ваш билет – **это подтверждение того, что** поездка застрахована.*

В сниженной (разговорной) речи допускается его пропуск: *Ваш билет – **это подтверждение, что** поездка застрахована.*

Comment: Спасибо большое, интересно! Значит, меня чутьё не обмануло.)

Comment: Чутьё у вас, Артем, просто потрясающее. Я к этому выводу пришла только через пару дней, обложившись книжечками, а вы сразу догадались. Спасибо, радуйте нас и дальше интересными вопросами.

Comment: Ну спасибо, захвалили прям!)))

Comment: Артем, вы не могли бы выполнить одну мою просьбу. Меня заинтересовал старый вопрос 2014 года  с обособлением частицы НЕУЖЕЛИ. Я попросила Александра ответить на него, а еще меня интересует ваше мнение, причем очень коротко: надо ли обособлять  и почему?  Именно мнение,  желательно интуитивное. Можно просто добавить комментарий к ответу Александра и проголосовать за него, если вы думаете так же, как он.  Я тоже отвечу на вопрос, но  позже, надо всё хорошо обдумать. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/Нужна-ли-запятая-в-сочетании-неужели-чтобы/461316?noredirect=1#comment475635_461316

Comment: С удовольствием, Sharon! Меня только удивляет от вас утвердительное "не могли бы". Это случайно?

Comment: Я задавал похожий вопрос про "Поэтому(,) чтобы...", и мне сказали, что в этом случае придаточное можно изъять, "поэтому" относится к главному, поэтому запятая нужна. Поэтому формально и тут мне то же видится. Но если действительно найдётся, чем оправдать вариант без запятой (тогда и в примере с "поэтому" тоже), мне это наверняка понравится.

Comment: Случайно, конечно. Да, надо тоже посмотреть "Поэтому(,) чтобы...". Но поэтому - это наречие, а неужели - частица.

Answer (score 4):

***Ваш билет — это подтверждение, что поездка застрахована.***

Это предложение нейтральное. Исходя из следующего, считаю, что ошибки нет.

[**Сложноподчиненные предложения с изъяснительной придаточной частью**](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-045.htm) (Валгина Н.С.)

> Изъяснительная придаточная часть может быть и **присубстантивной**, однако имена существительные, нуждающиеся в изъяснении, очень ограничены своей семантикой. Это отвлеченные **существительные** со значением восприятия, волевых и эмоциональных состояний, мыслительной деятельности, речи и подобные (*слух, сообщение, известие, заявление, угроза, сознание, убеждение, уверенность, чувство, мысль* и некоторые др.), **связанные происхождением или семантикой с соответствующими глаголами и сохранившие способность к управлению**. Например: *И все ясней и ясней становилась для него **мысль, что** существуют только три гордых призвания человека: наука, искусство и свободный физический труд* (Купр.).
>
> Такие изъяснительные придаточные части осложняются **определительным оттенком** значения, что связано с морфолого-синтаксической природой имени существительного.

Думаю, что слово "подтверждение" подходит к данному правилу:
***убеждение*** — *убеждать*,
***подтверждение*** — *подтверждать*.

И вдобавок — **примеры из Нацкорпуса**, которые не оставляют сомнений в правильности такого управления:

*Потом надо было еще раз получить от нее **подтверждение, что** она не сердится...* [Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)]

*― переспросил ее изумленный Подозеров и, получив от нее **подтверждение, что** она непременно пойдет в монастырь, не возразил ей ни одного слова.* [Н. С. Лесков. На ножах (1870)]

*Оно мелькнуло в уме не вполне разборчиво, но похоже было на **подтверждение, что** детям в Умани будет действительно хорошо.* [А. С. Макаренко. Книга для родителей (1937)]

*Получив от профессора **подтверждение, что** непосредственной опасности больше нет, Софья Яковлевна вошла в спальную.* [М. А. Алданов. Истоки. Части 1-8 (1942-1946)]

*Увы, почти в те же самые дни мы получили наглядное **подтверждение, что** это не так.* [Константин Симонов. Глазами человека моего поколения (1979)]

*Так или иначе, мы уже получили **подтверждение, что** операция Энского под странным кодовым именем «Норковая шуба» против Саши Корбаха прекращена.* [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (1997)]

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! А как разрешить разногласия насчёт тире?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой А разногласия в чём, с кем?  По-моему, всё по правилам. Подлежащее и сказуемое – существительные в им. падеже. Плюс **это** "усугубляет" применение тире. Или я что-то упускаю из вида?

Comment: Да, и олед то же говорил. Но вот Бегемотус говорит, что оно смотрится плохо.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Доброе утро, Александр. Не хотели бы вы ответить на один давний вопрос 2014 года. Там высказаны очень разные точки зрения, какая из них вам ближе? Может быть, нужно совсем другое решение, я пока никак не могу определиться. Не могли бы помочь найти истину.  А вопрос действительно интересный, он того стоит.https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/Нужна-ли-запятая-в-сочетании-неужели-чтобы

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо большое за предложение! Я ответил, но _совсем другого решения_ не нашел.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  О, большое вам спасибо. А то я уже пару часов думала и пока так и не определилась. Поэтому мне хотелось расширить спектр мнений, услышать что-то современное. Всё-таки тогда форум был немного другим, он вроде бы с 2012 года существует.

Comment: Александр, спасибо еще раз за ваш ответ. К сожалению, при всем моем искреннем расположении к вам, мне придется  выступить вашим оппонентом. Ну что мне еще от вас, редакторов и корректоров, ожидать: вы очень  любите  правила и ясные  ответы, прозрачные и однозначные (это шутка, чур, не обижаться!). Я свой ответ дам позже, задача у меня не из простых.

Comment: @Sharon Что вы, что вы! А я даже почти и не сомневался, что вы будете оппонентом. На счет корректора: я совсем не филолог и не лингвист, коррекцией занимаюсь время от времени по просьбе знакомых, имеющих своё небольшое издательство на базе центра ноосферного здоровья. И еще: вспомнился один мой [неоднозначный ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460395/Пунктуация-в-вопросе-И-что-вы-думаете-это-значит/460398#460398) (на грани фола), может, видели его?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Ноосфера?  А я думала, что это понятие устарело, теперь говорят об едином информационном (виртуальном)   поле вне времени и пространства. А корректором в этом вопросе выступает tat. Не видела я вашего неоднозначного ответа, но надо будет посмотреть Любопытно.

Comment: @Sharon  Наоборот – набирает оборот! Сейчас все сферы ноосферные! :)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: не слышал такого в единственном числе! Только *набирает оборотЫ.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Я специально так написал – рифма, игра слов...

Comment: Аааа, не догадался!))

Answer (score 2):

Можно ли пропустить указательное слово и почему тире "смотрится плохо"?

Это такой интересный случай, когда **письменная и устная речь оформляются по-разному**.

(1) В письменной форме: *Ваш билЕт **— это подтверждение тогО,** что поездка застрахована.*

(2) Запись устной речи: Ваш билет **это подтверждЕние, что** поездка застрахОвана.

В устной речи мы не можем разделить предложение на три фонетические фразы при отсутствии указательного слова, то есть **не можем сделать паузу перед ЭТО**.

Такую же интонацию имеет следующее предложение: *Ваш билет **подтверждАет, что** поездка застрахОвана.*

А при отсутствии придаточного мы имеем такое предложение: *Ваш билЕт — **это подтверждение вашей страхОвки**.*

Обратим внимание на то, что слово "подтверждение" имеет сильное управление и нуждается в зависимом слове или изъяснительном предложении, на которое **падает ударение.**

Таким образом, задача имеет **особое решение именно для данной структуры предложения**. Если мы в Нацкорпусе наберем фразу "***это подтверждение, что***", то результат будет нулевой. Для этого случая требуется указательное слово, например:

***Это подтверждение того, что** ученики академика Коптюга не только помнят о нём, но и продолжают его дело, в том числе и на Байкале.* [Владимир Губарев.  «Наука и жизнь», 2009]

***Это подтверждение того, что** мои записки достоверны.* [Мария Желнавакова. Письма Н. С. Фуделю (1987-1997) // «Альфа и Омега», 1999 | 2000]

В других конструкциях слово "подтверждение" не нуждается в обязательном указательном слове. Оно факультативно и может быть пропущено, что мы и видим из примеров в ответе Александра.

**Но вот нужного нам примера со словом ЭТО там нет...**

**И вывод.** Не стоит пренебрегать полученной информацией, если она не вписывается в наше понимание какой-либо темы. Возможно, мы что-то не учли в нашем решении ("упустили из вида").

Comment: Спасибо! Только в объявлении было ударение на "билет"! Вывод не совсем понял.((

Comment: Sharon, всё, конечно, хорошо. Хочу сказать лишь о том, что сам вопрос совсем не о тире. Прочитав комментарии, я не стал заострять внимание на нём, т. к. я тоже езжу в транспорте и постоянно слышу эту фразу. Диктор не произносит её скороговоркой, после слова "билет" есть явная (пусть и небольшая) пауза. И мне совсем непонятна утверждение, что **мы не можем сделать паузу перед ЭТО**. Как это не можем? Очень даже можем! И **тире плохо смотрится** – тоже из разряда субъективного...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  А вывод  Sharon касается моего ответа ("что-то упустил из вида" – из комментария).

Comment: Ну что я могу сказать? Спасибо всем за непонимание, мне не привыкать. Артем, я могу поставить ударение на «билете», главное же здесь то, что это предложение  плохо  делится на три ФОНЕТИЧЕСКИЕ фразы, а  нормально делится только на две, и люди чувствует это. Попробуйте произнести его с тремя явно выраженными паузами.  Ваш билЕт — это подтверждЕние, что поездка застрахОвана. Наше "притяжение" зависнет между ними, не зная, к чему притянуться.

Comment: Тогда попробуем прочитать  так: Ваш билЕт — это подтверждение, что поездка застрахОвана. То есть не будем делать грамматическую паузу перед союзом ЧТО, но так тоже читать неудобно. В общем, в устной речи все эти неровности сглаживаются, спорить о паузах не имеет большого смысла, а вот на письме, как я думаю, факультативное указательное слово становится практически обязательным.

Comment: Александр, вы же знаете, наверное, что существуют паузы произносительные, их нужно отличать от грамматических. Чтобы поставить тире перед связкой ЭТО, на слове билет делается силовое ударение, после которого следует хорошо подчеркнутая пауза, а у вас она небольшая. И еще к вам вопрос: что же вы не нашли примеры с ЭТО и пропуском указательного слова?  Ваши примеры, конечно,  хороши, но они к этой конструкции не имеют отношения. Я же как раз объясняю, что такие варианты на письме вряд ли существуют. Вам это хотя бы о чем-то говорит?

Comment: Я отвечал на вопрос о пропуске указат. местоимения. Произносительная пауза может идти (и идёт) после "билет". Она же отображается и грамматически с помощью тире. А вот второй паузы, перед "что", может и не быть (или совсем малюсенькая). Всё нормально читается и слушается. Мне вот наоборот, без тире "глаз режет". И ещё: вы же сами иногда говорите о фонетических крокозябрах при отсутствии знаков. Так получается и здесь: скопление Т и Д, _билеТэТопоДТвержение_. Про непонимание вы зря. Всё хорошо!

Comment: Нет, мне нравится ответ, забыл просто сразу проголосовать. Да, я догадался, что Sharon процитировала Александра, но всё равно плохо врубаюсь в вывод.)))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Артём, я тоже не сразу понял вывод, пока не дочитал до конца. Он целиком относится к моему ответу и комментариям, поэтому и не воспринимается как вывод самого ответа автора. Смысл такой: я пренебрег полученной информацией из комментариев о "нехорошем" тире, которая не вписывается в мое понимание темы, а сначала завуалированная фраза _"мы что-то не учли в нашем решении"_ поясняется в скобках цитатой из моего коммента.

Comment: Теперь всё понял) Спасибо, Александр! По-моему, Sharon права))